# У вас не получается оставаться дружелюбнЫМ vs. дружелюбнЫМИ

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, местоимения, множественное-число

Как правильно:

> У вас не получается оставаться дружелюбн**ым**

или

> У вас не получается оставаться дружелюбн**ыми**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас не получается оставаться дружелюбным. (Ед.ч.)
У вас не получается оставаться дружелюбными. (Мн.ч.)